# BACKUP DATABASE из linux sqlcmd

Tags: sql, ubuntu, sql-server, bash

Есть 2 сервера на винде 2008 и 2003 на обоиз стоит SQL Server 2005
запускаю бэкап из linux комадной:

```
sqlcmd -S tcp:192.168.0.1,1433 -U sa -P pass -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [db] TO DISK=N'db.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS=10, RETAINDAYS=7"
```

на 2008 все хорошо на 2003 выкидывает шибку:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Client unable to establish connection.
```

Порт открыт неблокируется

```
nc -z -v -w5 192.168.0.1 1433
Connection to 192.168.0.1 1433 port [tcp/ms-sql-s] succeeded!
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по ответам от Майкрософта, Windows Server 2003 не поддерживается, поэтому они не исправляют связанные с подключением к нему проблемы.

Соответственно, решение - обновить операционную систему.

Вот тут есть детали по подобной проблеме: https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/252

Comment: Может кто как то иначе организовал бэкап в linux базы MS SQL Server 2005 ?

Comment: А можно уточнить зачем такие сложные махинации? Почему нельзя запустить backup на Windows машине? Например, через SQL Server Agent на Windows. Так же вы можете запустить ту же sqlcmd локально на Windows машине через "Планировщик задач Windows"